# Execute new Process via Method Call in ClickOnce

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, clickonce

Our company uses ClickOnce to internally deploy our main application (AppA).  I'm in the process of writing a helper application (AppB) that, ideally, would be started via AppA.  We were planning on including AppB in AppA's solution, then adding a reference to AppB.

Is there any way to actually do something like Process.Start by calling AppB.Program.Main()?

Then, to add a level of complexity, how does this factor in with the ClickOnce deployment of AppA?

Any insight to point me in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for us was to see if they had already installed AppB by looking for the .appref-ms 'shortcut' in the Start Menu.  If they had it, do a Process.Start().  If not, send them to the Installation URL.

```
Private Sub LoadAppBFromClickOnce()
    Dim argsToPass As String = "?arg1=1"

    Dim s As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs), "CompanyName", "AppB.appref-ms")
    If File.Exists(s) Then
        Try
            Process.Start(s, argsToPass)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("AppB is not installed.  Please install from {0}.", APPB_INSTALL_URL), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Process.Start("iexplore.exe", APPB_INSTALL_URL)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

yes,  It can be done.  We have a click once application that calls an exe.  Here is the code

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = "Resources\\des.exe";
        Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-D -u -k \"6AAAAA(!\" " + encryptedFileName + " " + newFileName;
        Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Proc.Start();
        Proc.WaitForExit();
```

When we deploy it we need to deploy the des.exe in the Resources folder.  Also, we deploye it as full trust.